# Get information from a star review system

Tags: php, html

I know the title doesn't say a lot.

I'm making a site and I want people to review a book if they want to.
This code is on the page, under the product information:

```
      <span class='starRating'>
            <input id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
            <label for="rating5">5</label>
            <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
            <label for="rating4">4</label>
            <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3" checked>
            <label for="rating3">3</label>
            <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
            <label for="rating2">2</label>
            <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
            <label for="rating1">1</label>
      </span>
</select><br><br>
<button type='submit' onclick='comment.php'>Voeg toe</button>
<?php 
    $name = $_GET['Naam'];
    $comment = $_GET['Comment'];
    $rating = $_GET['rating'];
    if ($name != '' && $comment != '') {
    switch ($rating1) {
        case $rating = "1" :
            $ratingImg = '<img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg>';
            break;
        case $rating = "2" :
            $ratingImg = '<img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg>';
            break;
        case $rating = "3" :
            $ratingImg = '<img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg>';
            break;
        case $rating = "4" :
            $rating = '<img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg>';
            break;
        case $rating = "5" :
            $ratingImg = '<img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg><img src=/nl/images1/star-on.svg>';
            break;
    }
    $finalComment = "<?php 
    echo '<hr><p>Door: $name</p><p>Score: $ratingImg</p><p>$comment</p><br>';?>"
    ;
```

I would like to have the number of stars people select as a variable. I have the star system from [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/star-rating-widget/). When I send the from the following is in my URL bar: ...?rating=5&...

Can I get this in my `$ratingImg` variable? If my question is unclear, please say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$name = $_GET['Naam'];
$comment = $_GET['Comment'];
$rating = $_GET['rating'];
if ($name != '' && $comment != '') {
switch ($rating1) {
```

Change to

```
$name = $_GET['Naam'];
$comment = $_GET['Comment'];
$rating = $_GET['rating'];
if ($name != '' && $comment != '') {
switch ($rating) {
```

You dont have variable **$rating1**

Comment: I have it in a variable now, but no matter how many stars I select, $ratingImg only shows one star. I tried to switch the numbers around but that doesn't work either

Comment: `$finalComment = "<?php 
    echo '<hr><p>Door: $name</p><p>Score: $ratingImg</p><p>$comment</p><br>';?>"
    ;` change to
 
`$finalComment = "<hr><p>Door: $name</p><p>Score: $ratingImg</p><p>$comment</p><br>"; 
echo $finalComment;`

Answer (score 0):

Your switch is calling a variable called $rating1 which is not defined. It should be changed to just $rating

Typos are killer. =(